# Locale error with DatePicker of Vuetify in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem with the Datepicker of Vuetify. I'm using it in a nuxt environment.

I used the following code:

```
<v-template>
    <v-menu
        ref="datePicker"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        v-model="dateDialog"
        :nudge-right="40"
        :return-value.sync="date"
        lazy
        offset-y
        full-width
        min-width="290px"
    >
        <v-text-field
            slot="activator"
            v-model="date"
            label="Datepicker"
            prepend-icon="event"
            readonly
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-date-picker
            v-model="date"
            no-title
            color="secondary"
            :first-day-of-week="1"
            :reactive="true"
        >
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn flat color="black" v-on:click="dateDialog = false">Close</v-btn>
        </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
</v-template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'TimePicker',
        data() {
            return {
                date: '2019-01-15',
                dateDialog: false,
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Everything is working. But everytime I open the Dialog I get the following warning in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: The computed property "locale" is already defined as a prop.

found in

---> <VDatePickerDateTable>
       <VPicker>
         <VDatePicker>
           <ThemeProvider>
             <VMenu>
...
```

Does anyone know the reason for this warning? I'm using

```
"nuxt": "^2.1.0"
"vue": "^2.5.21"
"vuetify": "^1.3.14"
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to create a GitHub Repo with a reproduction of the problem, but there it is working without problems. The problem seems to be only in my current project. I can't find the reason there. Maybe someone else had this problem and solved it.